# Do I need extra preparation before sending Intent from another thread?

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, android-intent

*I use term Task **context** -- as C# Task type -- and Android **context** to differentiate those two entities.*

Better ask to be 100% sure -- when you work with WPF or WindowsForms you cannot interact with UI freely. For example when you use `await` you want to preserve the Task context (so no usual `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

So my question is -- when I try to send the intent from another thread do I have to make some preparation as well, say when I use `await` do I have to preserve Task context? Or is act of sending preparation itself -- something like (far fetched) analogy to `Dispatcher.Invoke` in WPF?

In other words can I just blindly send intent no matter what thread I am on, as long my Android context is valid? Or maybe it depends on the target thread -- when for example it is the main/UI one I should do something extra or it is guaranteed to work correctly always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have used the *async and await pattern* properly, then there should be no need to *marshal* back to the *UI thread*. It's the same as in *winforms* and *WPF*.

The exception to the rule is when you know you are **NOT** running on the *UI context* (i.e if you have used `Task.Run` to offload to another thread etc.), in which case you would call the following to *marshal* back to the *UI thread*:

[Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms)

> Invokes an Action on the device main (UI) thread.

The above is *Xamarin.Forms* equivalent of `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I use `Task.Run` :-) So to reiterate -- instead of just sending intent to UI, I wrap sending call with `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, correct?